# Communicating with child process in Python3 asyncio

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing

I have an asyncio based program (call it the server). The requirement would be to launch  other process from within this server, get back response from the process (these are long running) and further process/send out the collated response.

See the skeleton code below with comments on what I want achieved:

```
import asyncio
import subprocess

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()


def logFileProcessorBgThread(fName):
    print("Starting logFileProcessorBgThread")
    f = subprocess.Popen(['tail','-f', LOG_FILE], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    while True:
        line = f.stdout.readline().decode().strip()
        print(line)
        # somehow, send back the line to the start_server


async def start_server():
    # I want to start the logFileProcessorBgThread as a separate process,
    # one for each input file
    files = ["/var/log/syslog", "/tmp/somefile.log"]
    for f in files:
        # start logFileProcessorBgThread(f) as a process

    # need to build a way to receive the updates from the 2 process as an
    # when they have data..

    # my requirement is to bring back the responses to this process, so I can
    # further handle them (in my case send it out on a secure channel that
    # this process has established. Other launched process would not have
    # access to this channel..)



def main():
    loop.run_until_complete(start_server())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am not clear on how this streaming responses from the started process would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using a `ProcessPoolExecutor` combined with the `run_in_executor(..)` function in the event loop. Here's the basic tweak on your example:

```
import asyncio
import os
import time
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()


def process(filename):
    # do some work
    print("{} from process {}".format(filename, os.getpid()))
    time.sleep(2)
    return "response {}".format(filename)

async def start_server():
    # create the process pool executors with 2 workers (# of processes to use)
    pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(2)
    filenames = ["/var/log/syslog", "/tmp/somefile.log"]

    # launch them in the pool and then await on the results
    futures = [loop.run_in_executor(pool, process, filename) for filename in filenames]
    for future in futures:
        response = await future
        print("response was '{}'".format(response))


def main():
    loop.run_until_complete(start_server())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: In the example you have posted, the process() is returning something. My requirement (if you see  logFileProcessorBgThread) is it waits in an infinite loop, tailing a specific file. The goal is to pass the newlines (as they appear in tail) back to the parent.